# C# ASP.NET MVC Inconsistent Time

Tags: c#, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043326/A-Multi-Tenant-SaaS-Application-With-ASP-NET-MVC-A?msg=5402027#xx5402027xx

I'm reading this article and I've found one problem in this article.

The problem is when an user is creating an event at (31.05.2017 17:30:00) and the event date that being stored to the database is (31.05.2017 17:30:00), which is correct but it is in UTC format.

The reason I said it's being stored as UTC format is because when the form is displaying the date for that event it becomes (01.06.2017 01:30:00), which is Local Time format.

So can anyone please explain to me why is it happened?
And tell me how to fix it by converting the date format from user input to UTC format before that date is being stored to the database.

User input : 31.05.2017 17:30:00 (Local Time)
Database : 01.06.2017 01:30:00 (UTC)
Display : 31.05.2017 17L30:00 (Local Time)

Comment: Provide some code that shows how the user input travels to the database. We can't find anything wrong now without guessing.

Comment: I can't because the codes too long. There is a link up there and there is source code inside under Entities

And there is "public static Event create" and "public void SetDate"

Please forgive me that I asked you to go to that link